# <input type="email"> breaks ng-model data binding in modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

My app uses a modal dialog with a simple input element

```
<input id="fieldEmail" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="email" required="" />
email: {{ email }}
```

While the modal is being displayed, I can type something into the input field and see it echoed in the text beside it, as expected.  But if I change the input type to type="email" it breaks the data-binding.  Input is no longer echoed.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 9):

it will echoed only if input field has valid email.so put valid email in to input field and check it is working or not.this is because when `type="email"` `ng-model` only take valid email value,else it will `undefined`.

Comment: I want to show "required field" if email field is blank and "Invalid email id" in case of invalid email id. How can i show the validation for email type?

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the type "email". Even if we use type='number', then also the 'ng-model' will be undefined unless you enter some valid number in the text box. For all the HTML5 input types we should give the valid inputs to assign value to ng-model.
And even when we use regular expressions for text boxes, the ng-model will be undefined until we give a value which satisfies the regular expression.

'http://plnkr.co/edit/G2RlzO4q1zKEPP0T8xvF?p=preview`

```
<body>
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
Enter 3 to 12 characters only.
<br/>
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-pattern="/^[a-z]{3,12}$/"/>
<br/>
{{name}}
```

Comment: I want to show "required field" if email field is blank and "Invalid email id" in case of invalid email id. How can i show the validation for email type?